# Dialogflow: How to identify a specific string?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot, entities

How can Dialogflow get a specific string (login/id) in a phrase? I thought to create an Entity called "login" with all the logins as "synonyms".
Is it the best approach?

PS: I have more than 1500 logins/id and Dialogflow allows up to 200.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 1500 logins? Can you give an example of what you really want please

Comment: sorry, login is the same as a ID (string) in my context

Comment: I think you misunderstood the objective of Dialogflow, can you give us a real example, of what the user says and what information you are planning to fetch from the user and then what you plan to reply? Please give a real detailed example so we can guide you further

Comment: Example: "I'd like to know all the john's information"
The bot needs to get the "jhon" (login) from the phrase and consulting the information from an API.

Name,
Address,
Phone,

Etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the example in your comment, it seems you need to get the person's name.
Dialogflow offers a system Entity called **@sys.person**

> @sys.person: Common given names, last names or their combinations

You can also extend system entities if you want to add values that do not exist:

**Extend a system entity while annotating a training phrase:**

> From the intent page's training phrase section, you can extend a system entity while annotating a training phrase. If you manually annotate a training phrase part with an extendable system entity that does not include the selected value, you will be prompted to add this value to the system entity.

**Extend a system entity from the entities page**

> From the entities page, you can extend a system entity by following
>   these steps:
>
> ```
> Create an entity.
> Use the name of the system entity you want to extend. For example: sys.color.
> Provide entity entries using the values you want to extend the entity with.
> ```
>
> If you are using the API to extend system entities, create system
>   entity extensions similar to how you create developer entities.
>   Provide the name of the system entity you wish to extend, and provide
>   the values you want to extend it with. If you attempt to extend a
>   system entity that is not extendable, you will receive an err

[image]

Comment: Presently, the sys.person system entity is not extendable. ([ref](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/system-entities))